# Memory management - segmentation and paging

Tags: paging, memory-segmentation

Consider a memory management system with segmentation and paging in which a logical address is 32 bits, which include 12 bits for the offset, 9 bits for the segment number and 11 bits for the page number.
? What is the size of each page?
? What is the maximum number of pages per process?

Can you help me with that ? THANKS

Comment: Either a) Attend the lectures b) Read the notes/book that goes along with it c) Fail the course. It is your homework.

Comment: *What is the size of each page* - My guess is 2^11-1 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the size of each page?**

12 bit offset so,

Page size=2^12
         =4KBytes

**What is the maximum number of pages per process?**

Number of segments=2^9=512

Number of pages in a segment=2^11=2048.

I hope it helps....